# Excluding nodes in ways that are outside of intended area using Overpass API

Tags: area, query, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

The documentation for overpass states

> Nodes are found if they are properly inside or on the border of the area. Ways are found if at least one point (also points on the segment) is properly inside the area. **A way ending on the border and not otherwise crossing the area is not found.** Relations are found if one of its members is properly inside the area.

Which is as expected but also means that even if a way has nodes that fall outside of the area those nodes are still included. Is there a way to filter those out with Overpass QL?

Example query

```
relation(some_relation_id);map_to_area->.a;
(
  way(area.a)
  ['name']
  ['highway']
  ['highway' !~ 'path']
  ['highway' !~ 'steps']
  ['highway' !~ 'motorway']
  ['highway' !~ 'motorway_link']
  ['highway' !~ 'raceway']
  ['highway' !~ 'bridleway']
  ['highway' !~ 'proposed']
  ['highway' !~ 'construction']
  ['highway' !~ 'elevator']
  ['highway' !~ 'bus_guideway']
  ['highway' !~ 'bus_stop']
  ['highway' !~ 'footway']
  ['highway' !~ 'cycleway']
  ['highway' !~ 'trunk']
  ['service' !~ 'driveway']
  ['foot' !~ 'no']
  ['access' !~ 'private']
  ['access' !~ 'no'];
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

This will include a bunch of ways that are within the area of the relation id but it will also result in multiple nodes that are outside of the area.

One example might be relation id `1790696`. This way has nodes that are not within the relation area.

```
  <way id="146799177">
    <nd ref="1671127200"/>
    <nd ref="1600335278"/>
    <nd ref="3536447950"/>
    <nd ref="1671127206"/>
    <nd ref="1671127197"/>
    <nd ref="567267544"/>
    <nd ref="567267545"/>
    <nd ref="567266574"/>
    <nd ref="9083788041"/>
    <nd ref="1600351025"/>
    <nd ref="1671127193"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="track"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Four Mile Road"/>
  </way>
```